# Bug fixes for Evil Genius?

Tags: evil-genius

I've found a whole of lot bugs with Evil Genius, and I can't complete the game because of these issues.

Is there an updated copy of this game, or a patch one could install, to make this game completable?

Comment: Oh man! Just mentioning that makes me want to go and set up a bunch of wind traps and a piranha tank…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an official patch for Evil Genius (available at fileplanet amongst others), but there is also an unofficial patch here: http://www.n1nj4.com/EvilPlanet/TheGame/mod_unofficialpatch.php which adds a lot of tweaks.